# Explicit inverse for $U+\Lambda$ with $U$ orthonormal and $\Lambda$ diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I am searching for an explicit expression or at least an efficient way to compute the inverse of $U+\Lambda$ where $U$ orthonormal and $\Lambda$ is diagonal. My attempts so far were very unfruitful.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The inverse of an orthonormal matrix is it's transpose. The inverse of a diagonal matrix is just the reciprocals of it's diagonal entries. The inverse of a sum is the sum of the inverses with some extra garbage, see here: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690437

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but this applies only to rank one $\Lambda$. If I have a full rank diagonal matrix, I need to do $n$ recursions and do not gain anything.